# How to create an ArrayList and initialize new Byte variables in it

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am currently enrolled in the Udacity Android Basics Nanodegree program.
One task now is to create a ReportCard Java Class which would allow a school to store a student’s grades for a particular year.
While I submitted my project and it successfully passed review, I was given the suggestion of using an ArrayList instead of hard-coding the subjects for which grades could be given.
While implementing this suggestion, I am extremely struggling. I already searched throught StackOverflow for hours and haven't yet found a problem-solving answer.

So, here is my code:

```
package com.example.android.reportcardclass;

/**
 * Report Card class
 * This class prepares a student report card.
 */

public class ReportCard {

    /**
     * Class Attributes
     */
    private String mStudentName;
    private int mYear;
    private byte mGerman;
    private byte mEnglish;
    private byte mMathematics;
    private byte mGeography;
    private byte mSocialSciencesAndEconomics;
    private byte mPhysics;
    private byte mReligion;
    private byte mPhysEd;
    private byte mMusic;


    /**
     * Default Constructor for ReportCard class
     *
     * @param studentName                Name of the student
     * @param year                       Year in which the student is in
     * @param german                     Mark in the subject German
     * @param english                    Mark in the subject English
     * @param mathematics                Mark in the subject Mathematic
     * @param geography                  Mark in the subject Geography
     * @param socialSciencesAndEconomics Mark in the subject Social Sciences and Economics
     * @param physics                    Mark in the subject Physcics
     * @param religion                   Mark in the subject Religion
     * @param physEd                     Mark in the subject Physical Education
     * @param music                      Mark in the subject Music
     */

    public ReportCard(String studentName, int year,
                      byte german, byte english, byte mathematics,
                      byte geography, byte socialSciencesAndEconomics,
                      byte physics, byte religion, byte physEd,
                      byte music) {

        mGerman = german;
        mEnglish = english;
        mMathematics = mathematics;
        mGeography = geography;
        mSocialSciencesAndEconomics = socialSciencesAndEconomics;
        mPhysics = physics;
        mReligion = religion;
        mPhysEd = physEd;
        mMusic = music;
    }

    /**
     * This method is to get Student Name
     *
     * @return Student Name
     */
    public String getStudentName() {
        return mStudentName;
    }

    /**
     * This method is to set Student Name
     *
     * @param studentName Name of the student
     */
    public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
        mStudentName = studentName;
    }

    /**
     * This method is to get the year in which the student is in
     *
     * @return Year in which the student is in
     */
    public int getYear() {
        return mYear;
    }

    /**
     * This method is to set the year in which the student is in
     *
     * @param year Year in which the student is in
     */
    public void setYear(int year) {
        mYear = year;
    }

    /**
     * These are the setter and getter methods for the marks of the student in the respective subject
     */
    public byte getGerman() {
        return mGerman;
    }

    public void setGerman(byte german) {
        mGerman = german;
    }

    public byte getEnglish() {
        return mEnglish;

    }

    public void setEnglish(byte english) {
        mEnglish = english;
    }

    public byte getMathematics() {
        return mMathematics;

    }

    public void setMathematics(byte mathematics) {
        mMathematics = mathematics;
    }

    public byte getGeography() {
        return mGeography;

    }

    public void setGeography(byte geography) {
        mGeography = geography;
    }

    public byte getSocialSciencesAndEconomics() {
        return mSocialSciencesAndEconomics;
    }

    public void setSocialSciencesAndEconomics(byte socialSciencesAndEconomics) {
        mSocialSciencesAndEconomics = socialSciencesAndEconomics;
    }

    public byte getPhysics() {
        return mPhysics;
    }

    public void setPhysics(byte physics) {
        mPhysics = physics;
    }

    public byte getReligion() {
        return mReligion;
    }

    public void setReligion(byte religion) {
        mReligion = religion;
    }

    public byte getPhysEd() {
        return mPhysEd;
    }

    public void setPhysEd(byte physEd) {
        mPhysEd = physEd;
    }

    public byte getMusic() {
        return mMusic;
    }

    public void setMusic(byte music) {
        mMusic = music;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student Name: " + getStudentName() + "\nYear: " + getYear() + "German: "
                + getGerman() + "\nEnglish: " + getEnglish() + "\nMathematics: " +
                getMathematics() + "\nGeography: " + getGeography() +
                "\nSocialSciencesAndEconomics: " + getSocialSciencesAndEconomics() +
                "\nPhysics: " + getPhysics() + "\nReligion: " + getReligion() +
                "\nPhysical Education: " + getPhysEd() + "\nMusic: " + getMusic();
    }

}
```

What I want to do now, is to store the class attributes initialized at the very beginning (mGerman, mEnglish, etc.) in an ArrayList. How do I do that?! I am extremely struggling as I don't want to set any values just yet, but simply initialize the byte values (grading system in Germany goes from 0 to 15 points).

Please help me, thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You should probably considerate the use of HashMap as for key (German, English... as string or enum or object) and as value the mark. You will only need few method to set value. With this you can even think that some times a student don't follow every courses. And if you use object as key you can keep track of which student follow the course

Comment: Use numeric wrapper classes instead of primitive type. (`Byte` in your case)

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many grades there are going to be you can use the following to initialize an ArrayList with `null` values:

```
List<Byte> bytes = new ArrayList<Byte>(Arrays.asList(new Byte[9]));
```

To update values in the List you can use for example

```
bytes.set(3, (byte) 12);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But I should not hard code the length of the array. Furthermore, I do not want to set any value to the variables just yet, but only initialize them. That's what causing me headache.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ArrayList<ReportCard> mList=new ArrayList<>();

ReportCard reportCard=new ReportCard();
reportCard.setStudentName("student name");
//fill all the details like this
reportCard.setYear("2017");
.
.
mList.add(reportCard);
```

And when you want to get the details do like this

```
String studentName=mList.get(position).getStudentName();
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use an [`EnumSet`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/EnumSet.html) instead of a list to store the grades, for the following reasons:

- It provides a more compact representation in memory
- It only accepts values of well-defined grades thanks to enum
- It prevents duplicates
- It allows to check if a grade is present with O(1) complexity.

First define an enum with the grades:

```
public enum Grade {
    GERMAN, ENGLISH, MATHEMATICS, GEOGRAPHIC, SOCIAL_SCIENCES_AND_ECONOMICS,
    PHYSICS, RELIGION, PHYSICAL_EDUCATION, MUSIC
}
```

Then you can expose methods to add or remove a grade for example, that will delegate to the `EnumSet` methods:

```
private final EnumSet<Grade> grades = EnumSet.noneOf(Grade.class);

public boolean add(Grade grade) {
    return grades.add(grade);
}

public boolean remove(Grade grade) {
    return grades.remove(grade);
}
```